# php multi dimensional array to javascript not accesible through loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I am trying to pass a multidimensional array from php(values inserted dynamically in real scenario) to javascript and later those values are used inside the javascript, when I am trying to print the same using loop, the values are not getting printed, when I have checked the array[0].length it is shown *undefined*

Values getting printed when used with static indexes. 
PFB image for reference -
[image]

Could anyone please correct me where's my mistake, I have been trying to figure this out from long time, unable to get it to work. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?php
// PHP array
$myArray = array();
$myArray[] = array("id" => 1, "data" => 45);
$myArray[] = array("id" => 3, "data" => 54);
$myArray[] = array("id" => 2, "data" => 69);

$json = json_encode($myArray);
echo $json;
?>


<script type='text/javascript'>
// pass PHP array to JavaScript 
var books = <?php echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT) ?>;


// how to access 
for (var i=0;i<books.length;i++){
    for (var j=0;j<Object.keys(books[i]).length;j++){
       document.write("In Loop: "+books[i][j]);
    }
} 

console.log("Books length: "+books.length+"\n");
console.log("Books[0] length: "+books[0].length+"\n");

console.log("Out Loop: "+books[0]["id"]+"\n");
console.log("Out Loop: "+books[0]["data"]+"\n");
console.log("Out Loop: "+books[1]["id"]+"\n");
console.log("Out Loop: "+books[1]["data"]+"\n");
console.log("Out Loop: "+books[2]["id"]+"\n");
console.log("Out Loop: "+books[2]["data"]+"\n");
</script>
```

Comment: JS Objects don't have a length property. Use this to get the object's length: `Object.keys(books[0]).length`

Comment: Hey Josan, thanks for the reply, I though it worked alright, but the size and the values are being printed as "undefined" again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `books[i]` is an object. It has properties `id` and `data`.

But `j` in the loop is an integer so as example `books[0][0]` is undefined since the object has no property named `"0"`.

If you want to loop over the properties of each `books[i]` object you can use a simple `for in` loop:

```js
var books =[
 {id:1, data:45},
 {id:3, data:54},
 {id:2, data:69}
];


// how to access 
for (var i=0;i<books.length;i++){
    for (var prop in books[i]){
       document.write("In Loop: " + prop + '=' + books[i][prop] +'<br>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to use 1, 45 in the first iteration? how can i achieve that?

Comment: Can use `Object.values(books[i]).join(', ')` to produce string like `"1, 45"` and get rid of the for/in loop

Comment: Strongly suggest also that you forget `document.write()` even exists and use dom insertion methods instead. `document.write()` is very very rarely used in modern javascript

Comment: Yes @charlietfl, This is just rough code for testing.
Actually in my original requirement, I would have two variables say "id" and "data" and i will send them as parameters to another function inside this loop, so I would like to set 'em like this `id = prop.value(id); data = prop.value(data);`
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: probably but I don't get it...  why would you need a function and not just use `id = book[i].id`?

Comment: my bad, I just complicated this from the beginning, yes you are right, I can get my work done by using `books[i].id and books[i].data`
Thank you very much for all the help, appreciate it.